# Process forked out of Maven release:perform plugin ignores user's settings.xml?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

As per the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html), the Maven release:perform goal checks out the project and then forks a new Maven instance to build it. For some reason the forked instance appears to ignore the user's `settings.xml`, which causes an error in my case because that file has the definition of a property that is used to compose the repository's URL in the parent pom.

- User's **settings.xml**
  Definition of a property in a "nexus" profile which is always active.

  ```xml
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <properties>
        <dist.url>http://host.com/nexus/content/repositories</dist.url>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  ```
- Parent's **pom.xml**
  Usage of the defined property to compose the repository's URL.

  ```xml
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <url>${dist.url}/releases</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
  ```
- Command executed:

  ```xml
  mvn release:perform
  ```
- Output (after it indicates having successfully checked out, built, tested and packaged the project):

  ```xml
  [INFO] Uploading: ${dist.url}/releases/com/acme/access/my-project/1.0/my-project-1.0.jar
  [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
  [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] [INFO] Total time: 3.659s
  [INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 01 14:40:23 EDT 2012
  [INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 21M/307M
  [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [INFO] [WARNING] The requested profile "nexus" could not be activated because it does not exist.
  [INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project my-project: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.acme.access:my-project:jar:1.0 from/to nexus (${dist.url}/releases): Error transferring file: no protocol: ${dist.url}/releases/com/acme/access/my-project/1.0/my-project-1.0.jar -> [Help 1]
  ```

Notice how the forked Maven instance is trying to upload to ${dist.url}, which indicates that the property defined in settings.xml was not read. Also, the warning message informs that profile "nexus" was not found. I'm assuming that the main Maven instance passed the profile information down to the forked instance so it knew to look for it, but since it ignored (or did not find) the user's settings.xml, it could not find that profile.

The only way I have found to circumvent this is to manually specify the location of the `settings.xml` file through the use of Maven's command line `-s` argument "wrapped" by the plugin's `arguments` argument, as in

```xml
mvn release:perform -Darguments="-s C:\Users\theuser\.m2\settings.xml"
```

Is the plugin behaving in an expected/correct way? Is there a way to keep the property definition inside the user's `settings.xml` without having to specify the location of the file as I have done above?

More information:

- The problem seems to be specifically with the plugin not finding the user's `settings.xml`, as copying the profile information into the global `settings.xml` does cause it to work.
- The user's `settings.xml` is properly named/created because running `help:active-profiles` indicates that the profile is active. Manually building and deploying with `mvn clean deploy` also works correctly (ie, the repository URL is correctly calculated and the artifact is uploaded).

Comment: I think in my case similar type of issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636196/maven-issue-the-goal-you-specified-requires-a-project-to-execute-but-there-is

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not necessarily a bug in the maven-release-plugin. It seems that you ran into this Maven bug: [MNG-5224](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5224)
The bug should be fixed in Maven 3.0.4.

Comment: Agreed, good to know this behavior is considered a bug. Thanks!

Comment: I got the same problem with Maven 3.0.4 - r1232337

Comment: This is still the same with Maven 3.5.0

Comment: It still does not seem to work with maven 3.6.3, any idea if we should re-open or create a new ticket? If so, which one?