# Maven release:perform doesn't recognize keystore parameters

Tags: android, maven, maven-archetype, jarsigner, android-maven-plugin

I have generated my project using the [android-release archetype](https://github.com/akquinet/android-archetypes).
In its documentation is indicated to add the `android-release` profile inside the `settings.xml`file.

My `~/.m2/settings.xml` looks like this:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>   
    <profile>
      <id>android-release</id>
        <properties>
            <sign.keystore>absolute path</sign.keystore>
            <sign.alias>my_alias</sign.alias>
            <sign.storepass>pass</sign.storepass>
            <sign.keypass>pass</sign.keypass>
        </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

My parent `pom.xml`file is almost the same generated by the archetype (version 1.0.8):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myapp-android</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-android-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>myapp-android - Parent</name>

    <modules>
        <module>myapp-android</module>
        <module>myapp-android-it</module>
    </modules>

    <scm>
        <url>....</url>
        <connection>....</connection>
        <developerConnection>....</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <platform.version>4.1.1.4</platform.version>
        <android.dex.optimize>false</android.dex.optimize>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ignition-releases</id>
            <url>http://nexus.qype.com/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.jakewharton</id>
            <url>http://r.jakewharton.com/maven/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                <version>${platform.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
                <version>${platform.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.10</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.0</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                        <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                        <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                        <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                        <sdk>
                            <platform>16</platform>
                        </sdk>
                        <undeployBeforeDeploy>false</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                        <!-- We need this since our pom.xml is not inside repo root -->
                        <arguments>-f ./android/pom.xml</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <inherited>true</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <removeExistingSignatures>true</removeExistingSignatures>
                        <archiveDirectory />
                        <archive>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</archive>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <certs>true</certs>
                        <keystore>${sign.keystore}</keystore>
                        <alias>${sign.alias}</alias>
                        <storepass>${sign.storepass}</storepass>
                        <keypass>${sign.keypass}</keypass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.4</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                            <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
                            <version>4.4</version>
                            <scope>runtime</scope>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                    <configuration>
                        <proguardVersion>4.4</proguardVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.5.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <release>true</release>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>enforce-signing-properties</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>enforce</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <rules>
                                        <requireProperty>
                                            <property>sign.keystore</property>
                                            <message>The 'sign.keystore' property is missing. It must contain the path to the
                                                keystore used to sign the application.
                                            </message>
                                        </requireProperty>
                                        <requireFilesExist>
                                            <files>
                                                <file>${sign.keystore}</file>
                                            </files>
                                            <message>The 'sign.keystore' property does not point to a file. It must contain the
                                                path to the keystore used to sign the application.
                                            </message>
                                        </requireFilesExist>
                                        <requireProperty>
                                            <property>sign.alias</property>
                                            <message>The 'sign.alias' property is missing. It must contain the key alias used to
                                                sign the application.
                                            </message>
                                        </requireProperty>
                                        <requireProperty>
                                            <property>sign.storepass</property>
                                            <message>The 'sign.storepass' property is missing. It must contain the password of
                                                the keystore used to sign the application.
                                            </message>
                                        </requireProperty>
                                        <requireProperty>
                                            <property>sign.keypass</property>
                                            <message>The 'sign.keypass' property is missing. It must contain the password of the
                                                key used to sign the application.
                                            </message>
                                        </requireProperty>
                                    </rules>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>unix</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <rt.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/rt.jar</rt.jar.path>
                <jsse.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/jsse.jar</jsse.jar.path>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <!-- mac profile has to be after unix since running on mac will trigger both -->
        <profile>
            <id>mac</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>mac</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <!-- absolute path -->
                <!--<rt.jar.path>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/classes.jar</rt.jar.path> -->
                <!-- or with JAVA_HOME /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/ -->
                <rt.jar.path>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</rt.jar.path>
                <jsse.jar.path>${java.home}/../Classes/jsse.jar</jsse.jar.path>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <rt.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/rt.jar</rt.jar.path>
                <jsse.jar.path>${java.home}/jre/lib/jsse.jar</jsse.jar.path>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

When I run `mvn release:perform`looks like it doesn't find the informations about the keystore to use:

```
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building myapp-android - Parent 1.0
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-signing-properties) @ myapp-android-parent ---
[INFO] [WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty failed with message:
[INFO] The 'sign.keystore' property is missing. It must contain the path to the
[INFO]                                                 keystore used to sign the application.
[INFO] [WARNING] Rule 1: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireFilesExist failed with message:
[INFO] The 'sign.keystore' property does not point to a file. It must contain the
[INFO]                                                 path to the keystore used to sign the application.
[INFO] Some required files are missing:
[INFO] (an empty filename was given and allowNulls is false)
[INFO] 
[INFO] [WARNING] Rule 2: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty failed with message:
[INFO] The 'sign.alias' property is missing. It must contain the key alias used to
[INFO]                                                 sign the application.
[INFO] [WARNING] Rule 3: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty failed with message:
[INFO] The 'sign.storepass' property is missing. It must contain the password of
[INFO]                                                 the keystore used to sign the application.
[INFO] [WARNING] Rule 4: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty failed with message:
[INFO] The 'sign.keypass' property is missing. It must contain the password of the
[INFO]                                                 key used to sign the application.
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] myapp-android - Parent ......................... FAILURE [0.577s]
[INFO] [INFO] myapp-android - Application .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] myapp-android-it - Integration tests ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 1.862s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 31 21:24:41 CET 2013
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/81M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0:enforce (enforce-signing-properties) on project myapp-android-parent: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] myapp-android - Parent ......................... FAILURE [22.389s]
[INFO] myapp-android - Application .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] myapp-android-it - Integration tests ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23.799s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 31 21:24:41 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3:perform (default-cli) on project myapp-android-parent: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I tried also passing keystore parameters to the `release:perform`

```
mvn release:perform -Dsign.keystore=/path/to/keystore \
                    -Dsign.alias=key-alias \
                    -Dsign.storepass=keystore-password \
                    -Dsign.keypass=key-password
```

But with the same effect.

Any idea on how can I make it works?
It's probably something silly but I'm a beginner with Maven and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11767664/process-forked-out-of-maven-releaseperform-plugin-ignores-users-settings-xml) I've found that problem was caused from a Maven 3.0.3 bug. Updating to Maven 3.0.4 completely solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maven release:perform goal executes in a different context and your java parameters are not propagated.

Try using `-Darguments` option. For example: `mvn release:perform -Darguments="-Dsign.keystore=/path/to/keystore -Dsign.alias=key.alias"` and so on

Other options for that goal is available on the manual page: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html