# Maven Issue - The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory

Tags: svn, maven, maven-release-plugin

I am using maven release plugin 2.2.1 . In my case `release:clean` and `release:prepare` is executing successfully . But when I am trying to execute `release:perform` it show the following error.

```
EXIMR-IM-187:rabbit_trunk manojkumarbardhan$ mvn release:perform
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Curo Fabric Component for RabbitMQ 2.0.20-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.2.1:perform (default-cli) @ curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments ---
[INFO] Checking out the project to perform the release ...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/manojkumarbardhan/QURO_PROJECT/rabbit_trunk/target && svn --non-interactive checkout http://ssygh.dgxxxgdf.xxx.com:1080/SVNROOT/CURO/Experiments/migration/tags/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.19 /Users/manojkumarbardhan/QURO_PROJECT/rabbit_trunk/target/checkout
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/manojkumarbardhan/QURO_PROJECT/rabbit_trunk/target
[INFO] Executing goals 'deploy'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 0.115s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: Thu Sep 05 17:40:01 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 2M/81M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/Users/manojkumarbardhan/QURO_PROJECT/rabbit_trunk/target/checkout). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[INFO] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[INFO] [ERROR] 
[INFO] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[INFO] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.528s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Sep 05 17:40:01 GMT+05:30 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.2.1:perform (default-cli) on project curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I do not know what wrong i did.

The process I am following is :-

1. checking out from svn
2. cd to that checkout directory
3. Executing my necessary svn commands
4. Executing `mvn release:clean`
5. Executing `mvn release:prepare`
6. Executing `mvn release:perform`    , but it fails.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First thing release:perform does is check out the version tagged by release:prepare.  The log snippet shows this: `svn --non-interactive checkout http://istsvn.corp.apple.com:1080/SVNROOT/CURO/Experiments/migration/tags/curo-fabric-component-rabbitmq-experiments-2.0.19 /Users/manojkumarbardhan/QURO_PROJECT/rabbit_trunk/target/checkout`.  Check the /Users/manojkumarbardhan/QURO_PROJECT/rabbit_trunk/target/checkout directory, is there a POM in there?  If not, investigate why the checkout failed.

Comment: Yes , inside checkout the rabbit_trunk/pom.xml file is there.

Comment: Can you run a Maven install when that directory is the current?

Comment: @SanderVerhagen , current means you are saying to go into that directory then run maven install or some thing else.Is there any setup issue in pom.xml file.I am really do not know.

Comment: What I meant is traverse into the `checkout` directory and run a normal `mvn install` from there. It's a stupid, nothing little test, but it's the least to get started with.

Answer (score 1):

Developer connection from:

```
<scm>
  <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/myapplication/trunk/mycomponent/</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

should point to your maven project that you want to release.
Also, arbitrarily location can be used for release tag in plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <tagBase>https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/myapplication/releases</tagBase>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

One has to read usage page properly (which I also didn't do) and everything will work fine.
Still, I believe that plugin logging should give more precise information about the problem (or possible problems).